# Django admin urls return INVALID REQUEST! - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

my admin urls are sat behind a prefix by doing the following.

**1#**

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

is placed within **urls_core.py**

**2#**

```
(r'^api/', include('project.urls_core')),
```

is palced within **urls.py**

---

All admin URLs work fine except **app indexes**.

If I go to any URL such as:

- /api/admin/core/
- /api/admin/registration/
- /api/admin/users/
- /api/admin/filters/

**I receive 'INVALID REQUEST' as my response.** Status code is 200 (OK) though.

---

I have never received this error message before.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you also changed `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py accordingly?  
And secondly, I do not exactly know why you need to do what you do, but using a middleware for this purpose is could also be a solution!

Comment: @lazerscience ROOT_URLCONF points at project.urls

Comment: Why do you need to use this prefix?

Comment: @lazerscience because it's sitting behind IIS on a virtual directory... and there is no way I can change the settings!! If you can help that would be amazing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some middleware, that strips the leading api/ from the url should help you:

```
import re

class URLPrefixMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.path = re.sub('^api/','',request.path)
```

You shouldn't need your additional URL configuration then anymore. Put it in middleware.py in some app dir and add it to installed middleware!